# Oracle Query: Loop through columns dynamically to create rows

Tags: oracle, dynamic, union

I have the following Oracle database that can have any number of columns that may grow over time by user intervention in the web application.

```
ID | Name   | Football | WhoCreated  | When       | Baseball | Cheerleading | Swimming
1  | Billy  | (null)   |  sam, smith | (Timestamp)|   1      | (null)       |   1
2  | Susie  |  1       |  sam, smith | (Timestamp)| (null)   |   1          |   1
3  | Johnny |  1       |  Homer      | (Timestamp)|   1      | (null)       | (null)
```

I am trying to generate an output that looks like

```
2, Susie, Football
3, Johnny, Football
1, Billy, Baseball
3, Johnny, Baseball
2, Susie, Cheerleading
1, Billy, Swimming
2, Susie, Swimming
```

I can do this with a UNION, but I will have to adjust each for the specific name field. I'm already up to about 50 columns (50 unions), and that can grow at any time by users in the system. To further complicate things, I have a few columns for auditing purposes tucked in the middle of the list. I really need some sort of dynamic way of looping through the columns, I have searched, but none seem to address the issue I have.

Comment: What about normalizing your data model?

Comment: I did not design this database, I'm only doing the reporting. I'd love to curse out whoever thought this would be the best way to structure this.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea. I couldn't test it, but fairly simple to understand.

```
create or replace package test_pkg AS

  TYPE REP_CURS IS REF CURSOR;
  TYPE output_REC IS RECORD(
    id_    number,
    name_  varchar2(50),
    field_ varchar2(50));

  TYPE output_TAB IS TABLE OF output_REC;

  FUNCTION Get_Data RETURN output_TAB
    PIPELINED;

END test_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg IS

  FUNCTION Get_Data RETURN output_TAB
    PIPELINED IS

    output_REC_ output_REC;
    rep_lines_  REP_CURS;
    stmt_       VARCHAR2(5000);
    table_rec_  yourtable%ROWTYPE;

  begin
    stmt_ := '  YOUR QUERY HERE ';

    OPEN rep_lines_ FOR stmt_;
    LOOP
      FETCH rep_lines_
        INTO table_rec_;
      EXIT WHEN rep_lines_%NOTFOUND;

      output_REC_.id_   := table_rec_.id;
      output_REC_.name_ := table_rec_.name;

      if table_rec_.football IS not null then
        output_REC_.field_ := table_rec_.football;
        PIPE ROW(output_REC_);
      end if;

      if table_rec_.Baseball IS not null then
        output_REC_.field_ := table_rec_.Baseball;
        PIPE ROW(output_REC_);
      end if;

      if table_rec_.Cheerleading IS not null then
        output_REC_.field_ := table_rec_.Cheerleading;
        PIPE ROW(output_REC_);
      end if;

      if table_rec_.Swimming IS not null then
        output_REC_.field_ := table_rec_.Swimming;
        PIPE ROW(output_REC_);
      end if;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE rep_lines_;

    RETURN;
  exception
    when others then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error:' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE ||
                           DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK ||
                           DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);
  END Get_Data;

END test_pkg;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to have to test this out on a non production server.

Comment: My Oracle license is severely restricted by the vendor, I am getting insufficient privileges errors. I think I am going to have to just have to do this outside of SQL. I am going to hang onto that code though!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function and then use it, please consider the code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION commalist (par_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
  TYPE curs IS REF CURSOR;
  v_emp_cursor curs;
  fieldvalue   VARCHAR2(4000);
  var_out      VARCHAR2(4000);
  CURSOR col IS
  SELECT column_name
    FROM user_tab_columns
   WHERE table_name = 'TABLE';

BEGIN

  FOR reccol IN col LOOP
    OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR ('SELECT '||reccol.column_name||' val
                      FROM TABLE 
                     WHERE id = '||par_id);
    LOOP
      FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO fieldvalue;
        IF fieldvalue IS NOT NULL THEN
          var_out := var_out||fieldvalue||', ';
        END IF;
      EXIT WHEN v_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN SubStr(var_out, 0, Length(var_out) - 2);

END;
```

Comment: I have insufficient privileges to create a function. Unfortunately my license is restricted by the vendor. These answers are a goldmine though, I am going to save it for the future. I'm going to just attempt to dump the table over to Crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with src as (select 1 ID, 'Billy' name, 0 Football, 'sam smith' WhoCreated, sysTimestamp when,
                   1 Baseball, cast(null as number) Cheerleading, 1 Swimming
              from dual
            union all
            select 2, 'Susie', 1, 'sam smith', sysTimestamp, null, 1, 1
              from dual
            union all
            select 3, 'Johnny', 1, 'Homer', sysTimestamp, 1, null, null 
              from dual),

unpivottbl as (select *
                from src
                UNPIVOT 
                (
                   VAL
                   FOR descript
                   IN (Football, Baseball, Cheerleading, Swimming)
                ))

select ID, name, descript 
  from unpivottbl 
 where VAL = 1
```

Though it is not dynamic solution, you will need to add the columns for which you are going to unpivot the data. This is reference for [unpivot](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE).

Comment: That is a static solution. Please check title

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like a static solution may be my only hope. Any reason why I would use a unpiviot table as opposed to just Union statements? remember I got 50 or so columns on my real data.